# Only build specified branches

Tags: appveyor

I thought we had this nailed last week but this week it AppVeyor seems to have reverted to building on every branch.

There are only two branches we want to build on -`deploy/staging` and `deploy/production` but a new buildseems to be being triggered on all branches. Can anyone spot what's wrong with our appveyor.yml file?

```
for:
-
 branches:
  only:
    - deploy/staging
 configuration: Staging

 deploy:
 - provider: Environment
   name: staging.domain.com


- 
 branches:
  only:
   - deploy/production
 configuration: Release

 deploy: 
 - provider: Environment
   name: domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sharing common configuration between branches](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#sharing-common-configuration-between-branches) assumes that everything which does not included in `for` construct, is default configuration. This actually still could work for you even last week because it was the [bug](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/2092) which is fixed now :)

I would recommend [Conditional build configuration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#conditional-build-configuration), but without default configuration section. This may require some duplication in YAML, but will work for your scenario.

**UPDATE**: You can can also add the following into common configuration, and stay with `for` syntax:

```
branches:
  only:
    - deploy/staging
    - deploy/production
```